# Appengine migrate application stalled

Tags: google-app-engine

i have commenced migrated from master slave- HRD. The status has remained at 'running' for 3 days.
The same data (was bulk loaded) in another application was migrated in 30minutes.

how can i found out what is going on with my migration?

-lp

Answer (score 0):

You need to [file a production](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue) issue on the App Engine issue tracker, with your App ID(s) and any other relevant details.

Comment: i solved issue by reverting the migration and starting migration again. i dunno what happened but it migrated in 30 minutes.